# windows cmd batch if file exist run a batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i need to make a batch that looks for file

and once it exist it will run a windows cmd batch

i tried the below code but its not working

```
@ECHO off
IF EXIST C:\file.txt CALL batch.cmd
```

Comment: How did it fail?  As written it is fine, if the files exist where they should be.

Comment: Just a memo, it can fail if `file.txt` is a directory. To avoid that you have to write `if` statement twice: `if exist "c:\file.txt" if not exist "c:\file.txt\" call batch.cmd`

Answer (score 1):

I interpret "and once it exist..." as "keep looking and as soon as the file exists...". Use a loop:

```
@echo off
look:
timeout 1 >nul
IF NOT EXIST C:\file.txt goto :look
call batch.cmd
```

Note: never run a loop without a delay (`timeout` here) to avoid high CPU load)

Comment: This is a very good point.  When a file comes in from an FTP/SFTP Server, for example this would be great for an SMTP alert..

Answer (score -1):

If you like to write code all in a line, you should do it like this
`@ECHO off & IF EXIST C:\file.txt CALL batch.cmd`

Comment: You're right, though the text wasn't quite right and wasn't displayed correctly but it was on two lines.

Comment: One caution..  If you run this in a Batch Script however, you will need to double-up the ampersands: "&&" ..  Of course, if you do this from a command-line the single one will work just fine.

Comment: @Leptonator: a single `&` is fine in a batchscript. `&&` is a complete different story (it works as "if previous command was successful then"). Try `dir existent.txt && echo yes` and `dir notexistent.txt && echo yes`.

Comment: @Leptonator Double ampersands and single ampersands would work even if you run in a Batch Script

Comment: I agree.  As many of us have been bit by scripts a number of times, I like to separate or segregate the commands.  So the double-up on "&&" may help..  Agreed not in all instances..  if you don't need to play "script golf" you can just do it with separate lines too..  :)

Comment: @Leptonator: `&` and `&&` are completely different. `&` is a unconditional "and then" and will do the second comand independent of the success of the first comand. `&&` will only execute the second command only, if the first comand was successful. So doubling the `&` might change things dramatically (well, not with `echo off`, because this can't fail; but try my `dir` example from my last comment)